# Jittery xy coordinates when projecting a vector into NDC

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm playing a little around with ThreeJS and projecting vectors in the world space onto normalise device coordinates (NDC) and it works without any issue.

However I noticed that when panning quickly, there is significant amount of jitter in the x/y coordinate generated by the projection. This is less obvious for object #2 as it is orbiting around the origin, but for object #1 (that is placed at the origin) it should not change position at all even when panning the camera as it orbits around the origin anyway:

[image: Jitter of a projected vector placed at the centre of camera]

I first suspect that it is because the DOM updates aren't fast enough to catch up with the rAF callback, but it seems that when the x/y coordinates of object #1 is inspected, it still jitters. An example is when looking at just the x coordinate, you can see it jitters about the value of 323.50 when rotating the camera, even though the camera is pointed dead at the centre of the vector:

[image: Jitter of the x coordinate value when orbiting around the vector]

Example here:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
camera.position.set(2, 2, 2);

controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.2;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.45;
controls.update();

// NOTE: Append DOM overlays
const pointsToProject = [new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(2,2,-2)];
pointsToProject.forEach((_, i) => {
  const overlayElement = document.createElement('div');
  overlayElement.className = 'overlay';
  overlayElement.id = `overlay-${i}`;
  overlayElement.textContent = i + 1;

  document.body.appendChild(overlayElement);
});

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  const halfStageWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.5;
  const halfStageHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.5;

  pointsToProject.forEach((vector, i) => {
    const {
      x,
      y
    } = vector.clone().project(camera);
    const screenX = x * halfStageWidth + halfStageWidth;
    const screenY = y * halfStageHeight * -1 + halfStageHeight;

    const overlayElement = document.querySelector(`#overlay-${i}`);
    if (!overlayElement) return;

    overlayElement.style.setProperty('--x', `${screenX.toFixed(2)}px`);
    overlayElement.style.setProperty('--y', `${screenY.toFixed(2)}px`);
  });

  controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #555;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: translate(calc(var(--x, 0) - 50%), calc(var(--y, 0) - 50%));
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.146.0/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.146.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might need to call `camera.updateMatrixWorld();` prior to using `project(camera);`.

Comment: @ardget That actually did the trick: thank you so much! I've always though I need to call `camera.updateMatrixWorld()` if and only if I manipulated the camera position before performing the projection, but it seems this is necessary: if you can leave an answer below I'll be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: The `OrbitControls` is a class for controlling the camera, so the `camera.updateMatrixWorld()` is to be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minimal solution, call `camera.updateMatrixWorld();` before `project(camera)` so that the **current matrix** is used for calculation.

However practically, if the `overlayElement` and the `scene` need fully synchronize in every frame, call `controls.update()` and `renderer.render(scene, camera)` first, and then update the overlays, as follows.

```
controls.update();
renderer.render(scene, camera); // camera.updateMatrixWorld() is called in renderer.render()

// camera.updateMatrixWorld();

pointsToProject.forEach((vector, i) => {
  const {
    x,
    y
  } = vector.clone().project(camera);
  :
});

// controls.update();
// renderer.render(scene, camera);
```